# Copy field data from one table to another where matching id fields

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok I have two tables Clients and Quotes Both tables have an EnqNo column. Clients has two empty columns Project, Quote. Quotes has two columns Project and Estimate. I need to update Clients with the project and estimate fields from quotes where EnqNo matches. So Quote in Clients gets the values from estimate in Quotes for each row. Make sense?

I am struggling to get a query to work:

```
update Clients
set Clients.Project = Quotes.Project
from Clients, Quotes
where Quotes.EnqNo = Clients.EnqNo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an update statement for `MySQL`.

```
UPDATE Clients 
       INNER JOIN Quotes 
          ON Quotes.EnqNo = Clients.EnqNo
SET    Clients.Project = Quotes.Project
```

Answer (score 5):

SQL Server:

```
UPDATE Clients
SET Project = q.Project
FROM Clients c
JOIN Quotes q ON q.EnqNo = c.EnqNo
```

MySQL:

```
UPDATE Clients c
JOIN Quotes q ON q.EnqNo = c.EnqNo
SET c.Project = q.Project
```

Comment: this is a syntax for `TSQL`.

Comment: My bad, wasn't thinking straight